# What is the most efficient way to correlate a subquery on a big table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, correlated-subquery

I have a table that contains Make, Model, Serial Number, and Invoice Date of machine sales, and I want to pair that up with a table that contains Make, Serial Number, Recorded Usage, Usage Units, and Record Date - except that the Usage/Record Table is HUUUUUUGE and may not have a record for every machine.

I've tried writing an OUTER JOIN, but there's too much data in the Usage/Records table to make this operate efficiently. And I tried to write a CROSS APPLY, but I must have screwed something up, because that didn't seem to work very effectively, either.

Example of files:

My Base Query:

```
Inv. Date      Mk      Model      Serial
2019-03-29     AA      420D       0FDP09999
2019-03-21     AA      A19B-SSL   0DX240481
```

Usage/Records Table:

```
Mk      Serial      Usage      Units      Record Date
AA      0FDP09999   2345.0     H          2019-03-27
AA      0FDP09999   2349.2     H          2019-03-28
AA      0FDP09999   2351.8     H          2019-03-29
AA      0DX240481   0.0        H          2019-03-21
AA      0DX240481   24.0       H          2019-03-22
```

The output should be:

```
Inv. Date      Mk      Model      Serial      Usage      Units      Record Date
2019-03-29     AA      420D       0FDP09999   2351.8     H          2019-03-29
2019-03-21     AA      A19B-SSL   0DX240481   0.0        H          2019-03-21
```

... returning the Usage, Units, and Record Date of ONLY the most recent entry prior to the Invoice Date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Schemas and a query would also help.

Comment: How do you join the tables? On the `Serial` column? If yes, then for the `CROSS APPLY` (or rather `OUTER APPLY` in your case) to work efficiently you need a suitable index. In your case it would look like this: `ON (Serial, RecordDate) INCLUDE (Usage, Units)`. `INCLUDE` part is optional, most performance is gained from seeking into this index.

Comment: [Last_Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) might be of some use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I ended up creating additional queries outside what was originally my base query.

On the first outer query, I did this ("Invoice Number" is an additional field I invoked to ensure a unique row-numbering, in case a machine was sold once, bought back, and then sold again within the time period):

```
CASE
    WHEN Q1.[Usage] IS NULL
    THEN 1
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Q1.[Serial Number], Q1.[Mk], Q1.[Invoice Number] ORDER BY Q1.[Record Date] DESC)
END AS [RowNum]
```

This ensures that every entry in the table has a sorting mechanism, even if there's no Usage measurement in the joined table.

Then, the next outer query only grabbed the rows with RowNum = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a left join and `row_number()`.

```
SELECT t1.[Inv. Date],
       t1.[Mk],
       t1.[Model],
       t1.[Serial],
       t2.[Usage],
       t2.[Units],
       t2.[Record Date]
       FROM (SELECT t1.[Inv. Date],
                    t1.[Mk],
                    t1.[Model],
                    t1.[Serial],
                    t2.[Usage],
                    t2.[Units],
                    t2.[Record Date],
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[Inv. Date]
                                       ORDER BY t2.[Record Date] DESC) rn
                    FROM table1 t1
                         LEFT JOIN table2 t2
                                   ON t2.[Mk] = t1.[Mk]
                                      AND t2.[Serial] = t1.[Serial]
                                      AND t2.[Record Date] <= t1.[Inv. Date]) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

For performance try an index on `([Mk], [Serial], [Inv. Date])` for the first and `([Mk], [Serial], [Record Date])` for the second table. Or maybe try to switch the position of `[Mk]` and `[Serial]` if serials are more or less "unique" also over different makes.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this answer. This definitely helped to get me thinking in the right direction. Thank you so much!